# Woocommerce product grid individual background color

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add background color to individual products on the product grid woocommerce. The website doesn't have many products, it only has 10-15 products so I want to add the bg color of my choice to it. I have added an image of what I am trying to achieved

Comment: You can add custom color filed for particular product  using ACF or custom and get this color code as backgound.:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/color-picker/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's very Simple Process like:

1. Create Color code input field on add/edit product page on dashboard.
2. Save Custom color code input field value.
3. Set saved value(color code) and use accordingly.

**Example**

## functions.php

1. Create custom input filed on product setting tabs on admin(add/edit product)

   ```
     add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_bgcolor_fields');
     function woocommerce_product_custom_bgcolor_fields() {
        global $product_object;

        echo '<div class="product_custom_field ">';

        // Add Custom Product Color Field
       woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id'          => 'bgcolor',
        'label'       => __('Background  Color', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => 'Enter color code like #FFFFFF',
        'description' => __( 'Use this background color code on single product page', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'        => 'color', 
        'desc_tip'    => 'true' 
      ) );

      echo '</div>';
   }
   ```

2. Save custom product input field(bgcolor) values

   ```
    add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'woocommerce_product_custom_bgcolor_fields_save');
    function woocommerce_product_custom_bgcolor_fields_save( $product ) {
        if ( isset($_POST['bgcolor']) ) {
            $product->update_meta_data( 'bgcolor', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['bgcolor'] ) );
        }
    }
   ```
3. Set Background Color on Single Product Page

   ```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_set_product_custom_bgcolor' );
    function woocommerce_set_product_custom_bgcolor() {
        global $product;
        if ( $product->get_id()) {
            // Get product bgcolor code product wise.
            $bgcolor = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'bgcolor' , true );
            if($bgcolor){
                // Now you can use $bgcolor on style and you can change class/id accordingly.
                echo "<style>#page{ background-color:$bgcolor !important; }</style>";
            }
        }
    }
   ```

[image]

[image]